# JoinFaces @Configurable does not inject services

Tags: jsf, primefaces, joinfaces

I am migrating an old JSF application to newer versions.
I have the problem with the lazyDataModel of Primefaces

```
@Configurable
public class PerfilSeleccionLazyDataModel extends LazyDataModel<Perfil> {

    @Autowired
    private transient PerfilService perfilService;
```

Now these classes do not inject services and are null

My new project is with Spring Boot, JoinFaces 4 and Spring 5.

Can someone tell me what new strategy I should use or if I should add some extra confirmation, so that my services are injected well?

Answer (score 1):

I am using JoinFaces and here is what my LazyDatatable looks like.  Use JSF ViewScoped on the bean and use normal Inject to inject the bean you want.

```java
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class PerfilDatatable extends LazyDataModel<Perfil> {

    @Inject
    private transient PerfilService perfilService;
```

JoinFaces config:

```yaml
joinfaces:
  jsf:
    project-stage: Development
    state-saving-method: server
    facelets-refresh-period: -1
    facelets-skip-comments: true
    interpret-empty-string-submitted-values-as-null: true
    datetimeconverter-default-timezone-is-system-timezone: true
  primefaces:
    theme: babylon-bluegrey-accent
    font-awesome: true
    transform-metadata: true
    move-scripts-to-bottom: true
    submit: partial
  omnifaces:
    combined-resource-handler-cache-ttl: 3628800
    combined-resource-handler-disabled: true
  myfaces:
    support-managed-beans: false
    early-flush-enabled: true
    check-id-production-mode: false
```

Comment: it is still null, it has some configuration in the .yml files or some bean for JSF / JoinFaces. Thank you.

Comment: I added my JoinFaces YAML config.  Note I am using CDI and Myfaces Starters for JoinFaces.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar issue while using Spring-Boot-2.5.4 and JoinFaces_4.5.4. My solution is to pass the dependency from outside.

```
public class LazyProductsDataModel extends LazyDataModel<Product> {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private transient ProductRepository productRepository;

public LazyProductsDataModel(ProductRepository productRepository) {
    this.productRepository = productRepository;
}
}
```

and then in you can initialize it like this:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class ProductListView {

@Autowired
private ProductRepository productRepository;
private LazyProductsDataModel lazyProductsDataModel;

@PostConstruct
private void init() {
    lazyProductsDataModel = new LazyProductsDataModel(productRepository);
    }

}
```